# Matlab - Make binary the default base

Tags: performance, matlab

I've been using matlab to solve some boundary value problems lately, and I've noticed an annoying quirk. Suppose I start with the interval [0,1], and I want to search inside it. Naturally, one would perform a binary search, so I would subdivide the interval into [0,0.5] and [0.5,1]. Excellent: let's now suppose we narrow down our search to [0.5,1]. Now we divide the interval [0.5,0.75] and [0.75,1]. No apparent problem yet. However, as we keep going, representation of powers of 2 in base 10 becomes less and less natural. For example, 2^-22 in binary is just 22 bits, while in decimal it is 16 digits. However, keep in mind that each digit of decimal is really encoding ~ 4 bits. In other words, representing these fractions as decimal is extremely inefficient.

Matlab's precision only extends to 16 digit decimal floats, so a binary search going to 2^-22 is as good as you can do. However, 2^-22 ~ 10^-7, which is much bigger than 10^-16, so the best search strategy in matlab seems to be a decimal search! In any case, this is what I have done so far: to take full advantage of the 16 digit precision, I've had to subdivide the interval [0,1] into 10 pieces.

Hopefully I've made my problem clear. So, my question is: how do I make matlab count in native binary? I want to work with 64 bit binary floats!